# Nginx configuration issue - getting 404

Tags: nginx

I trying to configure Nginx to serve as a HTTP Load Balancer. Just for sake of prove of concept, I configured my nginx to redirect to ordinary http website (www.nationalrail.co.uk).

This is how my nginx configuration looks like:

```
http {

  upstream stream_backend {
     server www.nationalrail.co.uk:80;
  }


server {

listen 80;
error_log /home/ubuntu/logs/error.log debug;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://stream_backend;
   }
 }
}
```

However, when I going to my Nginx url (say, loadbalancer.com) - I receiving "404 - not found" error.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this ?

```
http {
  server {
    server_name loadbalancer.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://www.nationalrail.co.uk;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried exactly this - still 404

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the issue was due to http redirects. Redirects shall be explicitly handled inside Nginx, otherwise it doesn't works as expected.